# Cannot Select Direct Child from *goquery.Selection

Tags: go, jquery-selectors, goquery

In jQuery and CSS, you can use the `>` character which points to only the direct child element.

This works in [Goquery](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) with something like `doc.Find("body > ul")`, but when you already have a `*goquery.Selection` and you want to select a **direct** child element of the selection, how can this be done?

For example:

```
doc.Find("body > ul > li") // Works

doc.Find("body > ul > li").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    s.Find("> ul") // Does not work
})
```

I want to accomplish what you'd expect to be selected from the second block of code but I haven't had any success with this.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

As noted in [this cascadia ticket](https://github.com/andybalholm/cascadia/issues/18) (the selector library that goquery uses), this functionality is not (and will not be) implemented.

The simplest workaround would be to use the [`ChildrenFiltered()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.ChildrenFiltered) method on your selection:

```
doc.Find("body > ul > li").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    s.ChildrenFiltered("ul")
})
```

Comment: @Acidic: Does this help you?

Comment: yep, that's the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I'm having trouble with this again, it seems like `ChildrenFiltered` still captures deep children when I only want to restrict it to direct children.

Comment: @Acidic: please post a reproducible example of HTML and Go code of this behaviour.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Comparing https://github.com/andybalholm/cascadia/issues/18 and https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery/issues/117 was very frustrating!